# uiimageview animation stops when user touches screen

Tags: ios, animation, swift, uiimageview

I have a UImageview with animated image.
i am adding the uiimageview in code and its a part of a CollectionViewCell
When the user touches the cell the animation stops, why does this happen?

code:

```
 var images: [UIImage] = []
for i in 0...10 {
   images.append(UIImage(named: "image\(i)"))
}

        let i = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: 200, height: 200))
        i.animationImages = images
        i.animationDuration = 0.5
        i.startAnimating()
        i.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center
        i.userInteractionEnabled = false

        self.addSubview(i)
```

Comment: How about disable collectionView user interaction during animation?

Comment: Thanks, i disabled user interaction for the collectionView cell.
Now it Works.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4.0 Version:

```
override open var isSelected: Bool
{
    set {

    }

    get {
        return super.isSelected
    }
}

override open var isHighlighted: Bool
{
    set {

    }

    get {
        return super.isHighlighted
    }
}
```

Comment: how can I use it?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want any interaction then following will be the fastest way to resolve this issue:
`collectionView.allowsSelection = false`

Comment: You make my day! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your custom collection view cell class, write following methods to fix issue

```
func setSelected(selected:Bool) {

}

func setHighlighted(higlighted:Bool) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Overriding isSelected, isHighlighted with empty setter will solve this issue, but it will lose those two properties to be set. I was able to solve this issue by calling imageView.startAnimating() at didSelectItemAt in UICollectionViewDelegate.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let item = items[indexPath.item]
    if item.hasGIF {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! ItemCell
        cell.imageView.startAnimating()
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let item = items[indexPath.item]
    if item.hasGIF {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! ItemCell
        cell.imageView.startAnimating()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I can't disable selection or use any of the solutions posted before here. I do not need to highlight the cell so I disabled it through the delegate method below to return false which prevented the stopAnimating() method from being called. This was an issue I encountered when using the AnimatedImageView of KingFisher used in a UICollectionViewCell.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

> An array of UIImage objects to use for an animation. var highlightedAnimationImages: [UIImage]? An array of UIImage objects to use for an animation when the view is highlighted. The amount of time it takes to go through one cycle of the images.

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom UIImageView class and only stopped animation if I want it to stop.

```
class GifImageView: UIImageView {

private var stop = false

static func getAudioGif(_ size: CGFloat) -> GifImageView {
    return fromGif(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size, height: size), resourceName: "audio")!
}

override func stopAnimating() {
    if stop {
        stop = false
        super.stopAnimating()
    }
}

func stopForReal() {
    stop = true
    stopAnimating()
}

func fromGif(frame: CGRect, resourceName: String) -> GifImageView? {
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: resourceName, ofType: "gif") else {
        print("Gif does not exist at that path")
        return nil
    }
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    guard let gifData = try? Data(contentsOf: url),
          let source =  CGImageSourceCreateWithData(gifData as CFData, nil) else { return nil }
    var images = [UIImage]()
    let imageCount = CGImageSourceGetCount(source)
    for i in 0 ..< imageCount {
        if let image = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, i, nil) {
            images.append(UIImage(cgImage: image))
        }
    }
    let gifImageView = GifImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height))
    gifImageView.animationImages = images
    return gifImageView
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

In TableView Use code below can solve touche cancel, touche moved and so on

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [cell startAnimation];
}
```