# Animated ImageView hide in Collection View by tapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

My animated ImageView gets hidden if I press him in a cell. But there is no button and it should not disappear. Thats my code:

```
for (int x = 9; x > 0; x = x-1) {

        NSArray *imageArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-1.png",x]],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-2.png",x]],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-3.png",x]],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-4.png",x]],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-3.png",x]],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-2.png",x]],nil];

        [array addObject:imageArray];

    }


-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return feedArray.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSArray *contentArray = [feedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)contentArray.count] forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (contentArray.count == 1) {

        UIImageView *firstImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
        firstImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        firstImageView.animationImages = [contentArray objectAtIndex:0];
        firstImageView.animationDuration = 1.2;
        [firstImageView startAnimating];

    }
    return cell;

}
```

Can someone help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you have an code if the method - collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:, if so could you post it.

Comment: No I dont have that

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom collectionviewcell and override `setSelected:` and `setHighlighted:` as described in this previous answer, [uiimageview animation stops when user touches screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27904177/uiimageview-animation-stops-when-user-touches-screen).